# Issue with building an array for changing data into json for google API

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-visualization

I am building a simple report that I want to link to google's api to generate a line graph with the data, I am rather new to php and I cannot seem to get my data into json format. According the google's documentation the json format needs to be

```
"cols": [
    {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
],
"rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
]
}
```

I have built the query and tested this by its self and its works fine, my problem is building an array so that I can generate the correct json code. The code I am using to build this array and encode into json is:

```
function graphdata()
{
$array['cols'][] = array(
'id' => '',
'label' => 'DateCreated',
'pattern' => '',
'type' => 'string'
);
$array['cols'][] = array(
'id' => '',
'label' => 'UnitPrice',
'pattern' => '',
'type' => 'number'
);

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)){ 
$array['rows'][] = array (
'c' =>array(
array ('v' => $row->DateCreated->format('d-m-Y'), 'f' => ''),
array ('v' => $row->UnitPrice, 'f' => ''),
)
);
}
return $array;
}

print json_encode(graphdata());
```

Can anyone help with building this array, it doesn't seem to work at all but as far as I can see there is nothing that jumps out as being wrong, but saying that I am very new to php and no doubt i've done it wrong and it is a easy fix.

As a side note, I am using MSSQL.

More info following putting error reporting on:

Notice: Undefined variable: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: And what is the output of your `print json_encode(graphdata());`

Comment: It doesn't output anything I have just uploaded a new version with error reporting I've just updated my original post with the error I am receiving

Comment: Then, I think your connection to the database failed. `var_dump($conn)`

Comment: No the connection was established I thought that first of all

Comment: But your error says this: `sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource`. PHP is not lying, so the first parameter is not a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database queries are not working because the `$conn` variable is not defined in the scope of the function.

To solve that, [declare it as global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global):

```
global $conn;
```

or add it to your function as an [argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

```
function graphdate($conn)
```

The same goes for your `$query` variable.